# Inserting cookie in stubbed response from wiremock

Tags: cookies, wiremock

I have a simple wiremock stub for an endpoint.  The library that invokes this stub expects a cookie to be present in the response.  Is there an easy way to supply a cookie in the wiremock configured response

Sample code for stubbing an endpoint:

```
    stubFor(post(urlPathEqualTo("/endpoint"))
                .willReturn(aResponse()
                .withStatus(OK.getStatusCode())
                //with a cookie;
```

Is this doable? I am using the following wiremock version

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
  <artifactId>wiremock</artifactId>
  <version>2.19.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A cookie is nothing more than an HTTP header with the attribute name: "Set-Cookie". The below example is for the JSON variant, but should translate easily to the Java style: `.withHeader("Set-Cookie", "JSESSIONID=dcba")));`

```
{
    "metadata": {
        "title": "Cookie example",
        "description": "Example to return a Cookie",
    },
    "request": {
        "method": "ANY",
        "urlPath": "/returnCookie"
    },
    "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "headers": {
            "Set-Cookie": ["JSESSIONID=ABSCDEDASDSSDSSE.oai007; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly"]
        },
        "body": "This stores a cookie";
    }
}
```